# updating a field in MongoDb using Java Sync driver

Tags: java, json, mongodb, updates, localdate

I have tried to update a field in the MongoDB database namely the "Status" field (of type integer) only between two dates FromDate and ToDate.

no errors or warnings were obtained, however, the update is not reflected in the database.

[The form containing the data to be updated ...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hi5WL.png)

```
Json File [{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "6523d6f1af7d835017c39fcf"
  },
  "StudentName": "John Doe",
  "TutoringCourse": "Excel",
  "Course_details": [
    {
      "DateOfClass": "2023-03-21T00:00:00.000+00:00",
      "SessionStart": "16:00",
      "SessionEnd": "18:00",
      "HourlyWage": 12.5,
      "Duration": 2,
      "Cost": 25,
      "Status": 1,
      "Notes": ""
    },
    {
      "DateOfClass": "2023-03-31T00:00:00.000+00:00",
      "SessionStart": "15:00",
      "SessionEnd": "17:00",
      "HourlyWage": 12.5,
      "Duration": 2,
      "Cost": 25,
      "Status": 1,
      "Notes": ""
    },..]
}...]

Java code:
    public void UpdateOneCourseDetailsPerIntervalOfDate() {

    List <Bson> updateOperation = new ArrayList<Bson>() ;
    Bson update4,update5,update6,update7,update8,update9,update10;
//t[2] editbox with FromDate , t[3] editbox with ToDate
    LocalDate FromDate = LocalDate.parse(t[2].getText());
    LocalDate ToDate = LocalDate.parse(t[3].getText());
    //nameList contains students names
    if(nameList.contains(t[0].getText()) && !t[0].getText().isEmpty()) {
        Iterator<String> iterator = SelectedFieldsItems.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext())
        {
            String tmp = iterator.next();
            if(tmp instanceof String && tmp != "") {
            
            if(tmp == "SessionStart") {
                update4 = Updates.set("Course_details.$[].SessionStart", t[4].getText());
                updateOperation.add(update4);
            }
            if(tmp == "SessionEnd") {
                update5 = Updates.set("Course_details.$[].SessionEnd", t[5].getText());
                updateOperation.add(update5);
            }
            if(tmp == "HourlyWage") {
                update6 = Updates.set("Course_details.$[].HourlyWage", t[6].getText());
                updateOperation.add(update6);
            }
            if(tmp == "Duration") {
                update7 = Updates.set("Course_details.$[].Duration", t[7].getText());
                updateOperation.add(update7);
            }
            if(tmp == "Cost") {
                update8 = Updates.set("Course_details.$[].Cost", t[8].getText());
                updateOperation.add(update8);
            }
            if(tmp == "Status") {
                update9 = Updates.set("Course_details.$[].Status", t[9].getText());
                updateOperation.add(update9);
                }
            if(tmp == "Notes") {
                update10 = Updates.set("Course_details.$[].Notes", t10.getText());
                updateOperation.add(update10);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"No fields are selected..." ,"Update failed operation",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                return;
            }
    
        }//while loop
        
       try{
            DBConnection db = new DBConnection();
            Bson query = Filters.and(Filters.eq("StudentName", t[0].getText()),Filters.lte("Course_details.$[].DateOfClass", ToDate),
                    Filters.gte("Course_details.$[].DateOfClass",FromDate));

            UpdateResult r = db.getCollection().updateMany(query, Updates.combine(updateOperation));
            statusBar.setMessage("fields updated - count: " + r.getMatchedCount());
            }
        catch (MongoException me) {
            statusBar.setMessage("Unable to update fields: " + me);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            statusBar.setMessage("Student is not in database!");
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Student is not in database! please Check student name..." ,"Not in Database",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        }
            
}
```

The date field in MongoDb is :

[collection image in mongoDB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OQZgI.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
Course_details.$.Status
```

Also maybe worthwhile changing from `MongoException` to `Exception` to catch any other exceptions that may be thrown, or catch others in another catch block.